# 504 error received- is this an issue on the local or remote end?

Tags: http, ssis

I have an SSIS package that up until recently was working without issue. However, it is now failing sporadically with a `504` response (`GatewayTimeout`). Who is returning this response? The remote server or is the error on my side? I increased the timeout to 5 minutes but doesn't seem to have helped.

The very weird thing is, is that this works consistently if I run it manually through SSMS, but not when the job is scheduled. I can't think how a timeout issue would crop up based on the different ways the SSIS package is being run.

Edit: So I managed to get Fiddler working by logging in under the user that the SQL agent runs under.

A successful request returns the following header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 12 Sep 2016 22:35:36 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Server: xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Whereas a non-successful request:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Clutching at straws here, but would shouldn't be requests return the same heaeder values for `X-Server`, `Server` etc? I'm trying to ascertain whether this 504 is coming from the remote server or whether it is a proxy or something in between.

The request takes exactly 1 minute to time out.

Comment: first perhaps some background as far as what your package is doing and in particular what component is calling the url would be helpful.  Is it an internal url, external?  Is this part of a script component or script task if the former how many rows now versus before the issue happened.  I found a gateway timeout issue like this with a script component due to too many concurrent connections.  Firewalls, network appliances, new routes, gateway under more stress? AS far as remote or local it is local but because your remote server has not responded within X amount of time

Comment: executing SSMS versus scheduled.  Less records/requests involved? Is it possible the job is running more than once, are there other demands affecting resources at the scheduled time?

Answer (score -1):

Most common reason for different behaviour in manual/scheduled environment is different Windows account and permissions of the account. Maybe it can not connect to destination with scheduled account permissions and receives timeout.